# Shopper cannot see products - 403 Forbidden Response

Tags: ordercloud

Working through this [tutorial](https://ordercloud.io/learn/buyer-perspective/viewing-products).  I've created a buyer organization and buyer user `buyer01`, and I've added a product to the buyer's catalog.  I'd like to see that `buyer01` has access to that product.

When I [obtain an authentication token](https://ordercloud.io/learn/getting-started/making-your-first-request) using `buyer01`'s credentials, and send GET to `/v1/me`, I get this back:

```json
{
    "Buyer": {
        "ID": "BUYER_ORGANIZATION",
        "DefaultCatalogID": "BUYER_ORGANIZATION"
    },
    "Supplier": null,
    "Seller": {
        "ID": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    },
    "ID": "BUYER_USER",
    "CompanyID": "BUYER_ORGANIZATION",
    "Username": "buyer01",
    "Password": null,
    "FirstName": "Buyer",
    "LastName": "User",
    "Email": "buyer@email.com",
    "Phone": null,
    "TermsAccepted": null,
    "Active": true,
    "xp": null,
    "AvailableRoles": [
        "MeAdmin",
        "PasswordReset",
        "Shopper"
    ],
    "Locale": null,
    "DateCreated": "2022-12-21T00:43:53.507+00:00",
    "PasswordLastSetDate": "2022-12-21T00:43:53.543+00:00"
}
```

But when I try to see the products this user has access to, using GET `/v1/me/products`, I get back a 403 Forbidden response, with this body:

```json
{
    "Errors": [
        {
            "ErrorCode": "Auth.InsufficientRoles",
            "Message": "User does not have role(s) required to perform this action.",
            "Data": {
                "RequiredRoles": [
                    "Shopper"
                ],
                "AssignedRoles": [
                    "MeAdmin",
                    "PasswordReset"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Why does the first request show `shopper' role present, while the second shows it as missing?

Comment: The first request is essentially retrieving the profile information of "buyer01" and show the available roles not assigned roles, but what's interesting to me is that the MeAdmin role doesn't have access to the entire site, including products.

Comment: That was the issue. I recycled the Scope setting from the admin user, thinking that `shopper` was in that long list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. When I requested the access token for `buyer01`, I left the "Scope" setting as it was for when I earlier requested an admin token, assuming that "Shopper" was in the [documented](https://ordercloud.io/learn/getting-started/making-your-first-request) scope setting for the `admin01` user:

```
scope: "CatalogAdmin BuyerReader MeAdmin InventoryAdmin PasswordReset OrderAdmin PriceScheduleAdmin ProductAdmin ProductAssignmentAdmin ShipmentAdmin",
```

I see now that it doesn't have `shopper', so when I requested a new token with the [documented](https://ordercloud.io/learn/buyer-perspective/me-and-my-stuff) scope setting for the buyer user, I was able to get a 200 response:

```
scope: "MeAdmin PasswordReset Shopper",
```

```json
{
    "Meta": {
        "Facets": [],
        "Page": 1,
        "PageSize": 20,
        "TotalCount": 0,
        "TotalPages": 0,
        "ItemRange": [
            1,
            0
        ],
        "NextPageKey": null
    },
    "Items": []
}
```

The tricky part is that even though the user permissions returned in the first request included "shopper", the access token I requested didn't include that in the scope, hence the 403.

The astute reader will note that I am still not seeing my products, however. I'll update my answer when I figure *that* part out.

**Update**: The product assignment issue is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74891802/402949). The error was doing an assignment as a GET rather than a POST.

Comment: You might find some useful information here: https://ordercloud.io/knowledge-base/product-visibility

Comment: @M.Posthumus Thanks! I used that to isolate the root cause, and addressed in a separate Q&A, which I linked to above.