# Product Visibility

Tags: ordercloud

### Issue

When logged in as a buyer, I am unable to see a product I should have access to.  Issuing this request, **/v1/me/products** while passing a token for user **buyer01**, I see this response:

```json
{
    "Meta": {
        "Facets": [],
        "Page": 1,
        "PageSize": 20,
        "TotalCount": 0,
        "TotalPages": 0,
        "ItemRange": [
            1,
            0
        ],
        "NextPageKey": null
    },
    "Items": []
}
```

I expect to see the product **SHIRT** listed in the **Items** array element.

### Visibility rules

I've worked through the [Visibility Rules Checklist](https://ordercloud.io/knowledge-base/product-visibility#visibility-rules-checklist) and I believe all conditions have been met:

> - Product.Active = true
> - Catalog exists where:
>
>   - Catalog.Active = true
>   - Buyer is assigned via CatalogAssignment
>   - Product is assigned via ProductCatalogAssignment
> - One of the following is true:
>
>   - CatalogAssignment.ViewAllProducts = true

### Product is active

**{{baseUrl}}/v1/products** returns this response:

```json
{
    "Meta": {
        "Facets": [],
        "Page": 1,
        "PageSize": 20,
        "TotalCount": 1,
        "TotalPages": 1,
        "ItemRange": [
            1,
            1
        ],
        "NextPageKey": null
    },
    "Items": [
        {
            "OwnerID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "DefaultPriceScheduleID": "SHIRT_PRICE",
            "AutoForward": false,
            "ID": "SHIRT",
            "Name": "Cotton T-Shirt",
            "Description": "A plain white, cotton shirt for everyday use.",
            "QuantityMultiplier": 1,
            "ShipWeight": null,
            "ShipHeight": null,
            "ShipWidth": null,
            "ShipLength": null,
            "Active": true,
            "SpecCount": 0,
            "VariantCount": 0,
            "ShipFromAddressID": null,
            "Inventory": null,
            "DefaultSupplierID": null,
            "AllSuppliersCanSell": false,
            "Returnable": false,
            "xp": null
        }
    ]
}
```

### Catalog is active

**{{baseUrl}}/v1/catalogs** returns

```json
{
    "Meta": {
        "Page": 1,
        "PageSize": 20,
        "TotalCount": 1,
        "TotalPages": 1,
        "ItemRange": [
            1,
            1
        ],
        "NextPageKey": null
    },
    "Items": [
        {
            "ID": "BUYER_ORGANIZATION",
            "OwnerID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "Name": "Example Buyer",
            "Description": "Default catalog for Example Buyer",
            "Active": true,
            "CategoryCount": 0,
            "xp": null
        }
    ]
}
```

### Buyer is assigned

#### Buyer user in organization

{{baseUrl}}/v1/me (with buyer01 cookie) returns:

```json
{
    "Buyer": {
        "ID": "BUYER_ORGANIZATION",
        "DefaultCatalogID": "BUYER_ORGANIZATION"
    },
    "Supplier": null,
    "Seller": {
        "ID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    "ID": "BUYER_USER",
    "CompanyID": "BUYER_ORGANIZATION",
    "Username": "buyer01",
    "Password": null,
    "FirstName": "Buyer",
    "LastName": "User",
    "Email": "buyer@email.com",
    "Phone": null,
    "TermsAccepted": null,
    "Active": true,
    "xp": null,
    "AvailableRoles": [
        "MeAdmin",
        "PasswordReset",
        "Shopper"
    ],
    "Locale": null,
    "DateCreated": "2022-12-21T00:43:53.507+00:00",
    "PasswordLastSetDate": "2022-12-21T00:43:53.543+00:00"
}
```

#### Buyer organization is assigned catalog

**{{baseUrl}}/v1/catalogs/assignments** returns

```json
{
    "Meta": {
        "Page": 1,
        "PageSize": 20,
        "TotalCount": 1,
        "TotalPages": 1,
        "ItemRange": [
            1,
            1
        ],
        "NextPageKey": null
    },
    "Items": [
        {
            "CatalogID": "BUYER_ORGANIZATION",
            "BuyerID": "BUYER_ORGANIZATION",
            "ViewAllCategories": true,
            "ViewAllProducts": true
        }
    ]
}
```

### Product is assigned

This may be the issue. When I make the documented assignment:

**{{baseUrl}}/v1/catalogs/productassignments**

```json
{
    "CatalogID": "BUYER_ORGANIZATION",
    "ProductID": "SHIRT"
}
```

I receive a 200 response that does not show any assignment has occurred:

```json
{
    "Meta": {
        "Page": 1,
        "PageSize": 20,
        "TotalCount": 0,
        "TotalPages": 0,
        "ItemRange": [
            1,
            0
        ],
        "NextPageKey": null
    },
    "Items": []
}
```

Note that the above request, as all other steps, is taken from the Getting Started walkthrough. This step is provided under [Making Your Product Visible](https://ordercloud.io/learn/product-catalogs/making-your-product-visible).

This is confirmed by this request:

**{{baseUrl}}/v1/products/assignments**, which returns no products.

```json
{
    "Meta": {
        "Page": 1,
        "PageSize": 20,
        "TotalCount": 0,
        "TotalPages": 0,
        "ItemRange": [
            1,
            0
        ],
        "NextPageKey": null
    },
    "Items": []
}
```

### View all products is true

**{{baseUrl}}/v1/catalogs/assignments** returns

```json
{
    "Meta": {
        "Page": 1,
        "PageSize": 20,
        "TotalCount": 1,
        "TotalPages": 1,
        "ItemRange": [
            1,
            1
        ],
        "NextPageKey": null
    },
    "Items": [
        {
            "CatalogID": "BUYER_ORGANIZATION",
            "BuyerID": "BUYER_ORGANIZATION",
            "ViewAllCategories": true,
            "ViewAllProducts": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was making a GET request instead of a POST when doing this:

**{{baseUrl}}/v1/catalogs/productassignments**

When issuing a **POST**, the service returns a 204 No Content.

It is worth noting that the tutorial is a bit out of date--the current Product API documentation omits the above call, and instead has **/products/assignments** [here](https://ordercloud.io/api-reference/product-catalogs/products/save-assignment). This method will return a **405 Method Not Allowed** an error if doing a GET, which makes this issue easier to identify.

Now when I view **/me/products** as **buyer01** I see this:

```json
{
    "Meta": {
        "Facets": [],
        "Page": 1,
        "PageSize": 20,
        "TotalCount": 1,
        "TotalPages": 1,
        "ItemRange": [
            1,
            1
        ],
        "NextPageKey": null
    },
    "Items": [
        {
            "PriceSchedule": {
                "OwnerID": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "ID": "SHIRT_PRICE",
                "Name": "Cotton T-Shirt Price",
                "ApplyTax": false,
                "ApplyShipping": false,
                "MinQuantity": 1,
                "MaxQuantity": null,
                "UseCumulativeQuantity": false,
                "RestrictedQuantity": false,
                "PriceBreaks": [
                    {
                        "Quantity": 1,
                        "Price": 10.0,
                        "SalePrice": null
                    }
                ],
                "Currency": null,
                "SaleStart": null,
                "SaleEnd": null,
                "IsOnSale": false,
                "xp": null
            },
            "ID": "SHIRT",
            "Name": "Cotton T-Shirt",
            "Description": "A plain white, cotton shirt for everyday use.",
            "QuantityMultiplier": 1,
            "ShipWeight": null,
            "ShipHeight": null,
            "ShipWidth": null,
            "ShipLength": null,
            "Active": true,
            "SpecCount": 0,
            "VariantCount": 0,
            "ShipFromAddressID": null,
            "Inventory": null,
            "DefaultSupplierID": null,
            "AllSuppliersCanSell": false,
            "Returnable": false,
            "xp": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I've pushed a PR to fix the documentation: https://github.com/ordercloud-api/oc-documentation/pull/503